# OSX "install to usb" wont reboot to usb during install

Tags: high-sierra, usb, startup, install

Trying to install OSX High Sierra on an external USB drive. (I know. Old OS)
During install, the mac says it needs to restart.
When it restarts, it defaults to booting from the MAC, not the USB drive.
As such, the install never completes, and there is no way to boot from the install target drive.
I have tried every known solution:
NVRAM, SMC, Recovery Mode, Startup drive - which, since it doesn't finish, it only gives me the Question mark. Alt/opt key brings me to the sole internal hard drive, no other drives.
So to clarify, during install to a USB drive, how do I make sure that the computer completes the install, by properly rebooting?

Comment: Exactly how - from where, what state -  are you running the installer? I've seen instances where I've had to disconnect the extant OS drive to persuade this reboot to happen (but I'm on a Mac Pro where drives are rapidly swappable.)

Comment: Are you dead certain that your USB drive is bootable? If not, check out if that brand/model can be booted.